# Learning RubyMotion, trying to turn off autocorrection on a UITextView

Tags: ios, ruby, rubymotion

Alright, I'm just now learning me some RubyMotion so this is likely a n00b question. Here it goes.

I'm trying to turn off auto correction on a UITextView, which is normally done through the IB interface. Here's what I've got so far:

```
@myUITextView.setAutocorrectionType(UITextAutocorrectionType autocorrectionType.UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo)
```

This, of course, throws an error...

```
app_delegate.rb:10:in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:': undefined local variable or method `autocorrectionType' for #<AppDelegate:0xc06c970 ...> (NameError)
```

Any ideas? Cheers, thanks so much for any help.

Comment: It appears to me that you're passing in the type AND a value in the call to `setAutocorrectionType`. Try `@myUITextView.setAutocorrectionType(UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo)`

Comment: That worked. Post an answer and I'll select it, seeing as you _were_ first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to me that you're passing in the type AND a value in the call to `setAutocorrectionType`. Try:

```
@myUITextView.setAutocorrectionType(UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have an issue with your statement. Use the following:

```
@myUITextView.setAutocorrectionType(UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo)
```